# Como podria redefinir un EventEmiter cada x segundos

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, twitter, events

Tengo un sistema de notificaciones de Twitter el cuál usa un NPM que necesitas pasarle las IDS a seguir para notificar, el problema es el siguiente y es que las IDS vienen de MongoDB y obviamente llegan de manera asíncrona. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es redefinir el EventEmitter (stream) con las nuevas IDs cada 60 segundos, actualmente llevo esto pero no me llega a funcionar del todo bien.

```js
const TwitterFunction = async() => {
  console.log('Loading IDS')
  twitterData = await twitterSchema.find()
  IDS = []
  for (const data of twitterData) {
    IDS.push(data.userId)
  }
  console.log(IDS)
  stream = client.Twit.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: IDS })
  setTimeout(async() => {
    console.log('Changing interval')
    await TwitterFunction()
    console.log('Changing interval finished')
    stream.removeAllListeners('tweet')
    console.log('Listener removed')
  }, 60e3 )
  stream.on('tweet', (tweet: any) => {
    console.log('Tweet Recieved')
    // Manage the Event
  })
```

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que los `id`'s vienen de MongoDB a qué te refieres? ¿Debes consultar a MongoDB cada cierto tiempo para saber si hay nuevas?

Comment: Si, ya que los usuarios puede añadir/eliminar ID's con un comando.